# I am getting error while renaming column name or column datatype for tempoal table in TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-data-tools, dbdeploy

I am using Visual Studio enterprise 2017 (Version:15.71.1) and SSDT(Version:15.1.61804.210)
and also using TFS to keep my code. In my database project all tables are temporal table.

Now when i am changing column type or column name in TFS , i am not able to build my project so not able to generate publish script.

I am getting error :
***Error SQL71609: System-versioned current and history tables do not have matching schemas. Mismatched column:"XXXXX"***

Do we have any solution for this ?

Comment: Can you try running a schema compare and Update first? (make sure the source and target are correct)

Comment: problem is when i am changing column type in tfs it is not changing respective column type in History table.(For Example if i will write alter column statement in SSMS to change the column datatype.. in history table it will change automatically) . The same is not happening in TFS.

Comment: @AnunayaMishra Just try explicitly defining the history table, then manually keep the schema of the current and history table in sync. Reference this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940570/avoid-schema-mismatch-in-system-versioned-tables/41004522

Comment: The solution which worked for me , is to make these changes in SQL Server Object Explorer (You can see it by right clicking on DB project and choosing the “View in Object Explorer” option).

You need to do the modification here and just save it and it will work.   Don't know it is the correct way or not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which worked for me , is to make these changes in SQL Server Object Explorer (You can see it by right clicking on DB project and choosing the “View in Object Explorer” option). You need to do the modification here and just save it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can try explicitly defining the history table, then manually keep the schema of the current and history table in sync.

Reference this thread: [Avoid schema mismatch in System-Versioned tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940570/avoid-schema-mismatch-in-system-versioned-tables)

---

**UPDATE:**

As you mentioned the solution which worked for you is to make these changes in `SQL Server Object Explorer` (You can see it by right clicking on DB project and choosing the “View in Object Explorer” option). You need to do the modification here and just save it and it will work.